# Envers, for a ManyToOne with JoinColumn, is auditing the wrong column

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

When auditing a foreign key, Envers seems to be ignoring the JoinColumn annotation.

E.g. I have a simple class like this:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="addressTypeFk", referencedColumnName="EntityId",nullable=false)
    private AddressTypeLookup addressType;
```

Which references a lookup table like this:

```
@Entity
public class AddressTypeLookup
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String descr;
    private int entityId;
```

Notice that the addressType attribute on Address is joining to the entityId column, not the primary key "id" column. Also notice the use of RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED : I want to audit the foreign key, but I don't want to Audit changes to AddressTypeLookup. The problem is, when Envers records changes to the foreign key, it's recording the AddressTypeLookup primary key value "id", not the entityId. How do I make Envers record the entityId values used?

[In case you're wondering why I want this: we have a database of lookup data (aka master / reference data). It records history: all rows have effective from/to dates. The id column is properly unique; the entityId identifies a particular thing - e.g. all versions of a particular address type. All the lookup tables are replicated into an application database - but only the current data is replicated, not the historic data. ]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with the intersection of using referencedColumnName and RTAM.NOT_AUDITED. Please file a bug report @ https://hibernate.onjira.com/, envers component.

Comment: Thanks. I've now logged this in the hibernate jira site: [HHH-8066](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8066)