# Hibernate - Envers Writes Wrong Data to AUD Column

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am facing a problem with Envers. I have two entities, CITY and CITY_I18N.
There is an "One-to-Many" relationship between them, via "CODE" column of CITY entity.
When I try to save CityI18N entity, the operation ends successfully, but the record in CITY_I18N_AUD table contains wrong values, Envers writes "ID" column of CITY entity, instead of real foreign key, "CODE" column.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class City  {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CITY_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_CITY")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CITY_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @NotAudited
    private List<CityI18n> cityI18ns;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CITY_I18N")
@Audited
public class CityI18n {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CITY_I18N_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_APPLICATION")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CITY_I18N_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long ID;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_CODE", referencedColumnName="CODE")
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_CODE", referencedColumnName="CODE")
    private City city;
}
```

Comment: Only things I could say here is that it might be a bug in incorrect handling of `referencedColumnName`, as that's what is not standard in this example. But I haven't seen any reports like that before, so I don't think it's fixed in some future versions.

Comment: Hi Adam, actually, there is a similar post on stackowerflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340382/envers-for-a-manytoone-with-joincolumn-is-auditing-the-wrong-column?rq=1 A jira record was also created, https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8066

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, but I had the same exact issue recently and it seems it is still not addressed in Envers [yet](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8066).

My solution was to just let Envers write the data from the `@Id` column into the `referencedColumnName` column of the `_AUD` table.

It seems to be able to reconstruct the relationships fine.

The only obstacle is to manually change the SQL data type of the column in the `_AUD` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CITY_AUD (
    ID int8 NOT NULL,
    REV int8 NOT NULL,
    REVTYPE int2,
    REVEND int8,   -- if you are using ValidityAuditStrategy
    CODE varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, REV)
);

CREATE TABLE CITY_I18N_AUD (
    ID int8 NOT NULL,
    REV int8 NOT NULL,
    REVTYPE int2,
    REVEND int8,   -- if you are using ValidityAuditStrategy
    NAME varchar(255),
    CITY_CODE int8, -- Notice the type is int8 here - it will actually hold the CITY.ID not CITY.CITY_CODE
    LANGUAGE_CODE int8, -- assuming it's the same situation for LANGUAGE (wasn't clear from the question)
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, REV)
);
```

This might not work for all use cases, but it at least keeps relationship intact.