# Hibernate Envers doesn't save referenced column value in case of @OneToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Here's the code for 2 entities, `machine` and `device`.

```
@Audited
@Entity(name = "device")
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "machineCode", referencedColumnName = "machineCode")
    private Machine machine;

}

@Audited
@Entity(name = "machine")
@Table(name = "machine")
public class Machine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String machineCode;

}
```

Now, when i save the `device` entity. The `machineCode` column (in the auditing table of `device`) gets the value of `id` and not the corresponding `machineCode` from machine's domain object.
I am not sure if there is anything wrong with the code or not. Thanks in advance.

PS - there are other intermingled entities attached to `machine` entity as well. So, adding `@OneToMany` is not required or i should say, it would be an overhead.

---

Edit 1: this question is regarding the `envers` auditing framework if i didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Your "machineCode" field in "Machine" entity must be unique. You can try annotating it     with @NaturalId.

Comment: sorry @lutfucan, it didn't work.

Comment: See answer and comments to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160321/hibernate-envers-writes-wrong-data-to-aud-column

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, that the referenced entity(Machine) implements Serializable.

Check the below link for further clarifications:-

https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-model-association-dont-reference-primary-key-columns/

Comment: there is no mention of envers framework in the link buddy